# Failed resolutions of credentialsbuilder

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to continue an old android project of mine and started fixing issues with that. My program launches well in android virtual device but then goes background.(I tried it on my phone it doesn't do that) Then checked logcats and saw erros like below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/CredentialsOptions$Builder;
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.GoogleApiUtils.getCredentialsClient(GoogleApiUtils.java:29)
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.AuthViewModelBase.onCreate(AuthViewModelBase.java:30)
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.ViewModelBase.init(ViewModelBase.java:24)
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity.onCreate(KickoffActivity.java:38)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
```

App has facebook,google and mail login check at start and it is giving errors there as far as i understand.
Here is the deprecated code i have below;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    providers = new ArrayList<>();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        //USER ALREADY SIGNED IN
        Log.d("AUTH", auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        String firebaseuser = auth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
        String uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Log.i("myuserid: ", uid);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("firebaseuser", firebaseuser);
        intent.putExtra("firebaseuid", uid);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Log.d("AUTH222","burada");
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
                        ))
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RC_SIGN_IN){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            //users logged in
            Log.d("AUTH", auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            // users not authenticated
            Log.d("AUTH", "NOT AUTHENTİCATED");
        }
    }
}
```

After a bit research i found out that startactivtyforresult is depreceated, is it the reason for this to happen or something else?. if it is what is the correct way to fix this with registerForActivityResult method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the exact line of code that produces that error?

Comment: I have the same issue. Old project, trying to revive it.. updated all the apis from gradle and when running the app got the same error. Latest version for com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth is 21.0.0, but I managed to authorize by using version 20.7.0